# Procedural mesh comes out black in any shader

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, 3d-meshes, unity-shader-graph

I wrote a script that Creates a mesh procedurally

```
        mr = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mf = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        //
        mf.mesh = new Mesh
            {
                vertices = GetVertices(),
                triangles = GetTriangles()
                uvs = UpdateUVMap();
            };
 
        //assign material + shader.
        mr.sharedMaterial = new Material( Shader.Find("Shader Graphs/surface") );
```

(the mesh is a sphere for this example)

I created my Shader in shader-graph (any shader seems to have the same result)

When played, all seems good except that the object is black. What's happening?

//basic uv map example from docs

```
    public Vector2[] UpdateUVMap()
    {
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[this.vertices.Count];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < uv.Length; i++)
        {
            uv[i] = new Vector2(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].z);
        }

        return uvs.ToArray();

        //uvs.Clear();
        //uvs.AddRange(uv);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you remember to set or calculate normals for your mesh?

Comment: The triangles are clockwise so the normals are facing outward. Even if they were random I should still see something since the uv example is straight from the documents...

Comment: Did you [ask Unity to calculate normals for you based on vertex winding](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateNormals.html), or did you leave them at their default of (0,0,0)?

Comment: oh pfft, question averted! I was thinking the normal's were implied by the winding direction. didn't realize they were calculated/set separately. i been staring at this screen too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't explicitly provide normals to your newly-made mesh, they'll be left at their default values, and the default value of a `Vector3` is (0, 0, 0).

Any light vector dotted with a zero vector yields zero, so you effectively get no lighting this way: total blackness, just as you're observing.

If you want Unity to automatically compute normals for you based on the triangle information, call `mesh.RecalculateNormals();`

Note that this will give a smooth shading seam anywhere you have shared vertices, but it will create a [hard crease where you have vertex splits](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/162760/39518) (say, along a UV texturing seam). If that's not desired, you should compute your own normals and assign them the way you're doing with your vertex positions and texture coordinates.