# Material looks different on programatically generated mesh compared to resized default cube mesh

Tags: unity, c#, 3d-meshes, materials

I've written some code that generates a mesh from some 2D nodes, generating both triangles and vertices. It seems to have worked pretty well, since I get a solid mesh without any weird rendering artefacts:

[image: Mesh]

As you can already see in the preview, I am experiencing some problems with lighting and materials, despite the triangles and vertices being completely valid and wound correctly.

This is probably shown best by comparing this with a mesh created via right click > 3D Object > Cube, with the exact same material assigned as the programmatic mesh:

[image: Comparison of meshes]

I have tried calling `RecalculateNormals()` on the mesh, but this doesn't help.

I'm really stuck trying to work out what's going on, so any help is very much appreciated.

**Edit:**

In lieu of the code, here are the vertices and triangles that I'm using in this mesh:

```
Vertices: [(0.5, 0.0, 0.5), (0.5, 0.0, -0.5), (-0.5, 0.0, -0.5), (-0.5, 0.0, 0.5), (0.5, -0.5, 0.5), (0.5, -0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5)]

Triangles: [(3, 0, 1), (3, 1, 2), (5, 4, 7), (6, 5, 7), (0, 4, 5), (5, 1, 0), (1, 5, 6), (6, 2, 1), (2, 6, 7), (7, 3, 2), (3, 7, 4), (4, 0, 3)]
```

For @Phillip:

```
Mesh editing = Instantiate(new Mesh());

Vector3[] vertices;
int[] triangles;
GenerateVertices(out vertices);
GenerateTriangles(in vertices, out triangles);

editing.Clear();
editing.vertices = vertices;
editing.triangles = triangles;
editing.RecalculateNormals();
```

Comment: Can you please show us your code so we can check for any mistakes you might have made?

Comment: I'm reluctant to post all of it, because there's a lot. Any specific part that you would find useful @Philipp?

Comment: The code which builds the Mesh object. It's just 8 vertices, so that shouldn't be that much.

Comment: It looks like you're sharing the same 8 vertices among all 12 triangles, instead of [duplicating vertices for normal splits](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/162778/39518). This gives you one shared normal where three faces meet at a corner, so `RecalculateNormals()` will make this the average of the three face normals, giving your shading a smooth, blobby look instead of hard creased edges.

Comment: @DMGregory thank you! That's likely what's happening. I'll try duplicating vertices at normal splits and seeing if that solves it.

Comment: @Philipp you say that, but it's a full implementation of the Bowyer-Watson algorithm for Delauney triangulation, so it's about 200 lines. I'm creating the mesh by simple assignment of `mesh.triangles` and `mesh.vertices`, using the generated values which you can see in my edited question above.

Comment: @JThistle I am not so much interested in where those vertices come from but rather in the code which creates the Mesh object. For example, are you setting the vertices and triangles correctly? What about the UVs? What Recalculate* methods you are calling and in what order.

Comment: @Phillip I've edited the question to show what I'm doing in creating and configuring the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things missing from your mesh generation code:

1. You forgot to set any [uv](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-uv.html) (texture) coordinates for all corners of your triangless. You might wonder why you need those when your material doesn't even have a texture. The reason is that the Global Illumination engine requires UV coordinates for calculating its lightmaps, even for shaders which don't use textures.
2. You forgot to calculate a secondary uv map with [Unwrapping.GenerateSecondaryUVSet(mesh)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unwrapping.GenerateSecondaryUVSet.html) which is also required for some shaders.
3. You called RecalculateNormals() but you didn't call [RecalculateTangents()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateTangents.html). This is usually only required for materials which use a normal map, but it usually doesn't hurt to do it anyway in case you later decide to apply one which does.
4. You forgot to call [RecalculateBounds()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html). This is likely unrelated to the problem, but might cause other problems later related to culling.

Comment: I think the lack of vertex splits at the hard edges is the biggest problem here.

Comment: @DMGregory I would have agreed until I actually tried out Philipp's suggestion, and, using [`Unwrapping.GenerateSecondaryUVSet`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unwrapping.GenerateSecondaryUVSet.html) I actually managed to fix it perfectly! Seems that Unity uses the secondary UV set for lightmapping, and this function literally exists just for this purpose. Thanks either way.

Comment: Although, it wasn't necessary to set the primary UV coordinates.